# How can I using port 22 for vundle (vim bundle) in windows?

Tags: git, windows-7, github

I'm install [git for windows 1.8.5.2](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.8.5.2-preview20131230.exe&can=2&q=full+installer+official+git) on my Widnows7.

Somehow, github.com can be connected by port 22 from my computer, for example:

```
[Marslo@MJ ~/Desktop]
$ ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Bad file number
[Marslo@MJ ~/Desktop]
$ ssh -T -p 22 git@ssh.github.com
Hi Marslo! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
[Marslo@MJ ~/Desktop]
$
```

And, I've added the `Port 22` in `C:\Users\Marslo\.ssh\config`:

```
Host github.com
Port 22
User Marslo
Hostname ssh.github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

But, it still cannot work! The git repo will be clone by **port 443**:

```
[Marslo@MJ ~/Desktop]
$ git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git
Cloning into 'vundle'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; No error
```

What should I do can clone git repo by port 22 forcibly?

Comment: You can't just `git clone git@github.com:gmarik/vundle.git`?  (HTTPS is port 443; SSH is totally unrelated to that, but is the protocol Git uses when the repo URL doesn't specify one.)

Comment: Yes, I can. But [Vundle (vim bundle)](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) using **https** by automatically. I'm just using `https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git` by example.

Comment: Well, you can't use HTTPS on port 22 or SSH on 443.  22 is for SSH.  443 is for HTTPS.  You can't just up and change that and have anything useful happen.

Comment: **.ssh** file is affected when you use `git+ssh` mode for `git clone`. I've tested my acces to 443 port of **github.com**, and it succeeded, save the command line access. So try: `git clone git+ssh://ssh.github.com/gmarik/vundle.git`

Comment: @majioa Okay, seems something wrong with my network environment for https (at least for github's https).

Comment: to check connection to a port, try also: `telnet github.com 443`

Comment: @cHao Aright. I think I might need proxy. Is there any public proxy?

Comment: There doesn't need to be a public proxy.  Your internet access is screwy.  Fix that, and you fix the issue.  (Particularly check your router and your LAN for boneheaded restrictions.)

Comment: try ssh access as follows: `git clone git@github.com:gmarik/vundle.git`

Comment: @majioa, the result of `telnet github.com 443` is `Connecting To github.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 443: Connect failed`. What should I do?

Comment: @majioa, no, I cannot using ssh way, because vundle is using https.

Comment: I guess on the way of the packet is set the firewall: try `traceroute github.com` or `tracert github.com`. In which network you are resided?

Comment: You can use, it is just an access to the repos, which is provided by *github*, you can use ssh, https, and git r/o access. I gave you the variant of ssh access to your repo.

Comment: @majioa, can I using ssh way even if I'm not the collaborators? By the way, the network is okay, just cannot using port 443.

Comment: @Marslo why not? The three ways usage of git are available regardless of workprocess. So you can use the *ssh* way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [Quick start of vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle#quick-start), it can "Identification" the `git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<REPONAME>.git` way:

```
" non-GitHub repos
Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
```

Actually, not only for **"non-GitHub repos"**, but also including **GitHub repos**.

It just only modify the format from:

```
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
Bundle 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
Bundle 'kien/ctrlp.vim.git'
Bundle 'sjl/gundo.vim.git'
Bundle 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Bundle 'dantezhu/authorinfo'
Bundle 'Marslo/EnhCommentify.vim'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-pathogen'
....
```

To:

```
Bundle 'git@github.com:gmarik/vundle.git'
Bundle 'git@github.com:Yggdroot/indentLine.git'
Bundle 'git@github.com:kien/ctrlp.vim.git'
Bundle 'git@github.com:sjl/gundo.vim.git'
Bundle 'git@github.com:majutsushi/tagbar.git'
Bundle 'git@github.com:dantezhu/authorinfo.git'
Bundle 'git@github.com:Marslo/EnhCommentify.vim.git'
Bundle 'git@github.com:tpope/vim-pathogen.git'
Bundle 'git@github.com:gregsexton/MatchTag.git'
.....
```

And, vundle can `git clone` or `git pull` or do others only by port 22.

Answer (score 4):

Building on Marslo's advice, I found that all was solved by adding the line:

```
let g:vundle_default_git_proto='git'
```

to my `.vimrc` file so that vundle uses `git://` urls

Answer (score 1):

You may check connection to a port with:

```
telnet github.com 443
```

If should not return a connection error, but if yes the problem is in your netword settings.

Anyway, since an access to the repos can be used for all *GitHub* repos regardless of your workprocess, you can use three variants of access: *ssh*, *https*, and *git r/o access*.

The **.ssh** file is affected, when you use *git+ssh* mode for git clone. I've tested my acces to 443 port of github.com, and it succeeded, save the command line access. So if you have an ssh access, you can try:

```
git clone git+ssh://ssh.github.com/gmarik/vundle.git
```

or:

```
git clone git@github.com:gmarik/vundle.git
```

Comment: Yes， I've changed the title. Your method can handle github repos by manual. Actually, I need using vundle to handle much plugins in .vimrc.

Comment: @Marslo I'dont understand, you shell to clone the `vundle ` repo, or to use it?

Comment: You don't using vundle or vim right? You can see this is [my vimrc](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc#L69), there are much line looks `Bundle xxx` is for manage vim plugin by vundle (about 37 plugins). In this way, all plugin will be cloned by https way, that is using 443 port.

Comment: But, if I using [this way](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/Offline_Packages/Win/_vimrc_22#L69), it will clone by `git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git` way, it using port 22.

Comment: Actually, vim just a framework, you can see it just a shelf. I'm living with it's plugins (about 37 or more in future). :). It's okay if I clone them all by manual, but pull it a lots work. If vundle is using, I just needs run `:BundleInstall` to clone all of theme, and `:BundleUpdate` to pull the latest changes. That's very convenient for me.

Comment: @Marslo I use vim, but dont use the vundle =) So you just dont what to use the full record: `git@github.com:www/www.git`, just short `www/www`?

Comment: Using www/www is means it will be clone by `https://github.com/www/www.git`, it's defind in vundle itself. I'm understand it after I read it's source code. [I think you can found it at here](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/blob/master/autoload/vundle/config.vim#L47), [and here](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/blob/master/autoload/vundle/scripts.vim#L53)

Comment: @Marslo I see... I saw the vim code, I guess there are no way to clone a repo using *git* proto (not https)

Comment: Maybe I'm not explain clearly. My situation is, 443 port cannot be used (at least for git), so nothing can be clone by https way. (I cannot do anything, this is my network situation. It's public network, many people using it). The only thing I can do is using port 22 (ssh way) to handle vim plugins by vundle. (If I cannot changed the world, I can handle myself at least)  :)

Comment: @Marslo if you are a system admin, you could set port forwarding on your firewall, but this is an other story =)

Comment: Yes, :), If I'm the system admin or network admin, I've done that already. At first, I'm confusing for why port22 working and port 443 don't. After your explain, I understand https using port 443, and ssh using port 22. So, I just did little update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45476/discussion-between-majioa-and-marslo)